# Can't get 1920 x 1080 in Ubuntu via VMWare

Tags: 12.04, vmware, virtualization

I just installed Ubuntu and typed in `sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools`

I can change my resolution to 1920 x 1200, but not 1920 x 1080. Any ideas?

I've tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160509/how-to-go-full-screen-in-ubuntu-12-04-in-vmware-player-4-0), and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12578/adjusting-display-geometry-in-a-virtual-machine) but no luck. The second link is for VirtualBox

I've tried changing the VMWare settings on my host computer (Windows 8) and on my Guest OS (Ubuntu) with no luck. Really need this to work.

I don't think I'm running the vm tools correctly. Apparently I'm supposed to run the .pl file, but when I double click it, a text file just opens up.

xrandr:

```
xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 1 x 1, current 1360 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
Virtual1 connected 1360x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   800x600        60.0 +   60.3  
   2560x1600      60.0  
   1920x1440      60.0  
   1856x1392      60.0  
   1792x1344      60.0  
   1920x1200      59.9  
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1680x1050      60.0  
   1400x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1360x768       60.0* 
   1280x800       59.8  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1280x768       59.9  
   1024x768       60.0  
   640x480        59.9  
Virtual2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
Virtual3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
Virtual4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
Virtual5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
Virtual6 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
Virtual7 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
Virtual8 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

[image]

Comment: A little clarification - is the Ubuntu you just installed the host computer or the client computer?

Comment: Sorry, it's the client computer.

Comment: Maybe `xrandr --output Virtual1 --mode 1920x1080` works?

Comment: @ZDroid - It will mess up your dpi (fonts). Not instantly, but after a while it will.

Comment: Your resolution seems to be 16:10 (eg:1920x1200) and may not display @ 16:9 (1920x1080) properly.   
Is 1920x1080 possibile in Windows 8?

Comment: Yes Windows 8 has a resolution of 1920 x 1080. I have another Virtual Machine that is set to 1920 x 1080 and works perfectly.

Comment: are you sure the 3rd party drivers for the virtual 3D accelerator are installed and working? once the driver reports the resolution, xrandr should be able to list it (maybe).

Comment: This worked for me in VMWare workstation 15.0 on the Artix Linux Live CD (artix-xfce-runit-20210101-x86_64)

Answer (score 52):

My solution:

Create a text file with .sh extension. For example `setscreen.sh`

Insert the following text and save.

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode Virtual1 1920x1080
xrandr --output Virtual1 --mode 1920x1080
```

Run this .sh file as an executable. Screen should go to 1920x1080.

Use "startup applications" to launch the file at startup.

Note: I am running Mint 17 but this should work fine in Ubuntu.

Comment: This worked for me using Ubuntu 15.04 virtualized in VMWare Player with Windows 7 as the host OS.

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04 desktop with Vmware 8 on Mac Osx. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I was having this problem on ParrotSec OS 2.1 running on vmware. Works like a charm.

Comment: Worked for me on Debian 8.5 (Jessie) running on Vmware.

Comment: Worked for me In Ubuntu 17.04 / VMWare Workstation Pro

Comment: If you get an "Major opcode" error, shutdown the VM, go to VMWare VM settings from vSphere, open Video Card, click on "Video Memory Calculator", and select the highest resolution. This will raise up the "Total Video Memory" and let the video card reach that resolution.

Comment: Worked in VMWare Workstation 12PRO with Linux Mint 19.1.

Comment: Worked for VirtualBox 6.1, Ubuntu 20.04.  I get an error message from the first command, `X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)`, but since it works I'm not worried.

Answer (score 9):

I went to the same problem using Linux Mint Cinnamon 17.3 under VMware Player 12.1.

Reading more about `open-vm-tools` on the [VMware KB](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2073803), I found that using `open-vm-tools-desktop` package is the recommended way to work around this.

So I recommend you also execute a `sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools-desktop`. But keep in mind that the resolution will be auto adjusted only when on fullscreen mode, not when on windowed mode.

Comment: Actually the resolution gets adjusted when you adjust the window size. It works perfectly for me now. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Upvoted. [Ubuntu Help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VMware/Tools#Installing_VMware_tools_on_an_Ubuntu_guest) also described this solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can add a mode to `xrander`. For you, the command would be something like:

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

You might need to specifically state the output by adding the `--output Virtual1` option. I calculated this commands arguments with `cvt 19200 1080 60`. They could be different for you. Then just switch to that mode with this

```
xrandr --output Virtual1 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 60
```

Comment: Do you mean 1920x1080_60.00

Comment: @EGHDK yes, I have updated my answer. You might need to add the output option.

Comment: @EGHDK I would also sugest that you check out VirtualBox. It's an open source alternative to VMWare. It's guest additions does this automatically every time you resize the window, along with other features like a shared keyboard between host and virtual machine, and a seamless integration mode.

Answer (score 1):

[There is a workaround](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/969154/comments/18) by a guy called "dts-dreamer". It's attached as a patch on the bugtracker.

Now for the issue: It's a regression from 12.04 and it's still in the code as of 13.04.
The bug received a confirmed state on the bugtracker, but Canonical didn't comment yet.
Solution? None that I know.

The xorg.conf file also works for only some of the variants. Like Ubuntu itself and Kubuntu.
[Please flag the bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/969154) if it affects you (and if you have a Launchpad account.)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into that same problem. I had vmware tools installed and could not get it to go to full screen. What you want to try is in virtual machine (ubuntu) change the resolution there. It worked for me. For some reason it did not dynamically recognize the resolution i wanted and I had to manually change it for ubuntu.

Comment: What settings do you have set in VMWare player?

Comment: The setting I have for display are: Accelerte 3d Graphics checked and Use Host settings for monitors selected. Changing these settings  did not help me. If you need any other settings please ask.

Comment: Updated my question to show a quick snapshot of Ubuntu. The resolution get's to 1920 x 1200, but totally skips 1920 x 1080. My WIndows 8 is set to 1920 x 1080.

Comment: Unfortunetly, like you I only get the 1920 x 1200 setting while my win 7 is 1920 x 1080p. I find the 1680 x 1050 is better than 1920 x 1200. Sorry,I cant think of anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to dward's answer, I found that I had to use this command:

```
xrandr --addmode Virtual1 1920x1080_60
```

after I had entered dward's first command:

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

Then I was able to select the resolution in settings.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

1. Install open-vm-tools-desktop and reboot

   apt install open-vm-tools-desktop && reboot
2. Install fuse and reboot

   apt install fuse && reboot
3. set VM View->Autosize to **Autofit Guest**

I tried  installing everything at once and then rebooting and resizing, it didn't work for some reason, maybe because of the apt upgrade I had done before installing open-vm-tools-desktop. The above solution worked when I did that before any package upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Power on the virtual machine.
Log into the virtual machine using an account with administrator or root privileges.
Go to Virtual Machine > Install VMware Tools (or VM > Install VMware Tools).

Note: If you are running the light version of Fusion, a version of Workstation without VMware Tools, or VMware Player, you are prompted to download VMware Tools before they can be installed. Click Download Now to begin the download.

Open the VMware Tools CD mounted on the Ubuntu desktop.
Right-click the file name that is similar to VMwareTools.x.x.x-xxxx.tar.gz, click Extract to, and select the Ubuntu Desktop to save the extracted contents.

The vmware-tools-distrib folder is extracted to the Ubuntu Desktop.
To install VMware Tools in Ubuntu:
Open a Terminal window. Run this command to navigate to the vmware-tools-distrib folder:

> cd Desktop/vmware-tools-distrib

Run this command to install VMware Tools:

> sudo ./vmware-install.pl -d

Note: The -d switch assumes that you want to accept the defaults. If you do not use -d, press Return to accept the defaults or supply your own answers.

Enter your Ubuntu password.
Restart the Ubuntu virtual machine after the VMware Tools installation completes.